# Comparing rows to see if a customer has switched products

Tags: r

I have an Excel workflow that I'm trying to convert to an R script but can't figure out how do convert the formulas to something R can understand.

Given the small example table below I want to find out if a given customer has switched from one product to another and how many days there are between two given dates recorded on the customer. In Excel this is quite easy to do:
To find if there has been a switch I'd use "=IF(AND(B2=B1,D2<>D1),1,0)". Here I get a 1 if the Ids are identical from one row to the next and the product changes. Otherwise I get a 0. 
To count the days between the dates I'd use "=IF(B2=B1,DATEDIF(A1,A2,"d"),0)".

Ideally I'd like to only get a count of the number of days a customer has used a given product, where the number of days displayed for the last date is relative to today's date, but that is probably too complex...

Is there a quick and easy way of getting from the initial to the final table in R?

Example data:

```
Date <- c("1/1/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/4/2019", "1/20/2019", 
          "1/24/2019", "2/6/2019", "3/2/2019", "3/25/2019", "4/9/2019", 
          "4/24/2019", "5/1/2019", "5/6/2019", "5/13/2019", "5/15/2019", 
          "1/1/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/4/2019", "1/20/2019", "1/24/2019", 
          "2/6/2019", "3/2/2019", "3/25/2019", "4/9/2019")

Id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7)

Value <- c(991, 434, 741, 509, 421, 904, 728, 172, 341, 903,
           367, 378, 351, 906, 178, 649, 264, 935, 988, 694,
           334, 884, 545)

Product <- c("Product A", "Product B", "Product B", "Product C",
             "Product A", "Product A", "Product A","Product D",
             "Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product D",
             "Product C", "Product D", "Product A", "Product A",
             "Product A", "Product A", "Product A", "Product A",
             "Product B", "Product C", "Product D")

df <- data_frame(Date, Id, Value, Product)

df$Date <- mdy(df$Date)

# Initial table:
# A tibble: 23 x 4
   Date          Id Value Product  
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 2019-01-01     1   991 Product A
 2 2019-01-03     1   434 Product B
 3 2019-01-04     1   741 Product B
 4 2019-01-20     1   509 Product C
 5 2019-01-24     3   421 Product A
 6 2019-02-06     3   904 Product A
 7 2019-03-02     3   728 Product A
 8 2019-03-25     2   172 Product D
 9 2019-04-09     4   341 Product A
10 2019-04-24     4   903 Product B
11 2019-05-01     4   367 Product C
12 2019-05-06     4   378 Product D
13 2019-05-13     4   351 Product C
14 2019-05-15     4   906 Product D
15 2019-01-01     5   178 Product A
16 2019-01-03     5   649 Product A
17 2019-01-04     5   264 Product A
18 2019-01-20     5   935 Product A
19 2019-01-24     5   988 Product A
20 2019-02-06     5   694 Product A
21 2019-03-02     6   334 Product B
22 2019-03-25     7   884 Product C
23 2019-04-09     7   545 Product D

Final table:
# A tibble: 23 x 6
   Date          Id Value Product   Switched Days_between_dates
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01     1   991 Product A        0                  0
 2 2019-01-03     1   434 Product B        1                  2
 3 2019-01-04     1   741 Product B        0                  1
 4 2019-01-20     1   509 Product C        1                 16
 5 2019-01-24     3   421 Product A        0                  0
 6 2019-02-06     3   904 Product A        0                 13
 7 2019-03-02     3   728 Product A        0                 24
 8 2019-03-25     2   172 Product D        0                  0
 9 2019-04-09     4   341 Product A        0                  0
10 2019-04-24     4   903 Product B        1                 15
11 2019-05-01     4   367 Product C        1                  7
12 2019-05-06     4   378 Product D        1                  5
13 2019-05-13     4   351 Product C        1                  7
14 2019-05-15     4   906 Product D        1                  2
15 2019-01-01     5   178 Product A        0                  0
16 2019-01-03     5   649 Product A        0                  2
17 2019-01-04     5   264 Product A        0                  1
18 2019-01-20     5   935 Product A        0                 16
19 2019-01-24     5   988 Product A        0                  4
20 2019-02-06     5   694 Product A        0                 13
21 2019-03-02     6   334 Product B        0                  0
22 2019-03-25     7   884 Product C        0                  0
23 2019-04-09     7   545 Product D        1                 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Switched = as.numeric(Product != lag(Product, default = Product[1])), 
         Days_between_dates = as.numeric(Date - lag(Date, default = Date[1])))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 23 x 6
# Groups:   Id [7]
   Date          Id Value Product   Switched Days_between_dates
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01     1   991 Product A        0                  0
 2 2019-01-03     1   434 Product B        1                  2
 3 2019-01-04     1   741 Product B        0                  1
 4 2019-01-20     1   509 Product C        1                 16
 5 2019-01-24     3   421 Product A        0                  0
 6 2019-02-06     3   904 Product A        0                 13
 7 2019-03-02     3   728 Product A        0                 24
 8 2019-03-25     2   172 Product D        0                  0
 9 2019-04-09     4   341 Product A        0                  0
10 2019-04-24     4   903 Product B        1                 15
11 2019-05-01     4   367 Product C        1                  7
12 2019-05-06     4   378 Product D        1                  5
13 2019-05-13     4   351 Product C        1                  7
14 2019-05-15     4   906 Product D        1                  2
15 2019-01-01     5   178 Product A        0                  0
16 2019-01-03     5   649 Product A        0                  2
17 2019-01-04     5   264 Product A        0                  1
18 2019-01-20     5   935 Product A        0                 16
19 2019-01-24     5   988 Product A        0                  4
20 2019-02-06     5   694 Product A        0                 13
21 2019-03-02     6   334 Product B        0                  0
22 2019-03-25     7   884 Product C        0                  0
23 2019-04-09     7   545 Product D        1                 15
```

Comment: Thank you!!

It never ceases to amaze me how I can get answers in just minutes on questions where I've been stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `base R`

```
df <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$Id), function(v) {
  v$Switched <- c(0,ifelse(diff(match(gsub(".*?\\s","",v$Product),LETTERS))!=0,1,0))
  v$Days_between_dates <- c(0,diff(v$Date))
  v
}))
```

such that

```
> df
         Date Id Value   Product Switched Days_between_dates
1  2019-01-01  1   991 Product A        0                  0
2  2019-01-03  1   434 Product B        1                  2
3  2019-01-04  1   741 Product B        0                  1
4  2019-01-20  1   509 Product C        1                 16
8  2019-03-25  2   172 Product D        0                  0
5  2019-01-24  3   421 Product A        0                  0
6  2019-02-06  3   904 Product A        0                 13
7  2019-03-02  3   728 Product A        0                 24
9  2019-04-09  4   341 Product A        0                  0
10 2019-04-24  4   903 Product B        1                 15
11 2019-05-01  4   367 Product C        1                  7
12 2019-05-06  4   378 Product D        1                  5
13 2019-05-13  4   351 Product C        1                  7
14 2019-05-15  4   906 Product D        1                  2
15 2019-01-01  5   178 Product A        0                  0
16 2019-01-03  5   649 Product A        0                  2
17 2019-01-04  5   264 Product A        0                  1
18 2019-01-20  5   935 Product A        0                 16
19 2019-01-24  5   988 Product A        0                  4
20 2019-02-06  5   694 Product A        0                 13
21 2019-03-02  6   334 Product B        0                  0
22 2019-03-25  7   884 Product C        0                  0
23 2019-04-09  7   545 Product D        1                 15
```

**DATA**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17899, 17900, 17916, 
17920, 17933, 17957, 17980, 17995, 18010, 18017, 18022, 18029, 
18031, 17897, 17899, 17900, 17916, 17920, 17933, 17957, 17980, 
17995), class = "Date"), Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7), Value = c(991, 434, 741, 
509, 421, 904, 728, 172, 341, 903, 367, 378, 351, 906, 178, 649, 
264, 935, 988, 694, 334, 884, 545), Product = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Product A", "Product B", 
"Product C", "Product D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be missing the switch in row 13, though.

Comment: @Economist Sorry that I had a typo in my code, but now it is fixed. So the result should be the right one now....